# Not able to create loop with goto statement

Tags: c, loops, goto

Hey everyone I created this program to calculate the net amount a customer has to pay after the discount .
It calculates the discount on either millcloth or handloom items. I tried to use goto to create a loop that terminates when you enter a choice that is neither handloom nor millcloth, but it terminates after just one iteration. How do I create a loop with goto that will terminate only when I enter the wrong alphabet?

```
// a clothes showroom has announced a discount on mill cloth and handloom items , wap using switch and if //stmts to compute the net amount to be paid by customer
#include<stdio.h>
float netmillcloth(float a)
{
    if(a>300)
    a-=0.10*a;
    else if(a>200)
    a-=0.075*a;
    else if(a>100)
    a-=0.05*a;
    
    return a;
}


float nethandloom(float a)
{
    if(a>300)
    a-=0.15*a;
    else if(a>200)
    a-=0.10*a;
    else if(a>100)
    a-=0.075*a;
    else 
    a-=0.05*a;
    
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    char item;
    float purchase_amt, net;     // net is amount to be paid after discount
    input:
        
        
        printf("Enter the type of item bought\nM for millcloth\nH for handllom items\nother key to end program\n");
        scanf("%c",&item);
        
        switch(item)
       {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                printf("\nenter purchase amount:");
                scanf("%f",&purchase_amt);
                net=netmillcloth(purchase_amt);
                break;
            case 'H':
            case 'h':
                printf("\nenter purchase amount:");
                scanf("%f",&purchase_amt);
                net=nethandloom(purchase_amt);
                break;
            default:
                goto stop;
        }

    
printf("\nThe final amount to be paid is:%f\n\n",net);
goto input;
stop:
    printf("\nEnd of program");
        
    
}
```

I used goto statement but it did not result in a loop

Comment: Why would anyone want to create a loop using `goto`? There are 3 different loop variants in C that are way better than a `goto`. There are some situations where a `goto` is suitable, loops are none of them.

Comment: When asking debugging questions in the future, include a [mre]. That includes stating **exactly** the input you provided to the computer. For example, you might say “I typed `m` and pressed Return, and the computer printed ‘enter purchase amount:’. I entered “34” and pressed Return, and the computer printed ‘End of program’. I expected it to wait for me to type a character, but it did not.” In this case, I knew what the problem likely was because we have seen it so many times before on Stack Overflow. But, to work with computers, you must learn to write precisely about what the computer does.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `scanf` leaves the `'\n'` in the buffer so the second loop reads it and `switch` goes to `default:`

Read the string cleaning the buffer.

```
int main()
{
    char item[10];
    float purchase_amt, net;     // net is amount to be paid after discount
    input:
        
        
        printf("Enter the type of item bought\nM for millcloth\nH for handllom items\nother key to end program\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        switch(item[0])
        {
            /* ... */
```